# Android 403 Forbidden errors YouTube Data API request?

Tags: java, android, api, youtube, youtube-api

Using the YouTube API search method in my Android app (built in Android Studio) I am making a call that looks like this:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet........&key=MyAPIKey
```

I can get this to work with a YouTube API 'Server' or 'Browser' key, but not an 'Android' key.

I am using `keytool -V -list -alias androiddebugkey -keystore ~/.android/debug.keystore -storepass android -keypass android` to get the SHA1 output.  Then I use this ouput and my package name like the example below in my YouTube Android applications list in the Google Developers Console.

```
MY:SHA1:OUT:PUT;com.mysite.mypackage
```

Seems like I should be getting data from my API request, but I am not.  My app is throwing a `java.io.FileNotFoundException: https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search...` error, and getting a 403 forbidden response from the API.

Is there some additional setup that needs for this authenticaion to work in Android Studio?